# Metrics/AbcSize: Assignment Branch Condition size for chart_wise_results is too high. (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I am trying to solve the mentioned offense
firstly, my function looks like this

```
  def chart_wise_results
    require 'colorize'
    require 'time'

    _arg, year, path, _month = ARGV
    folder_name = path.split('/')
    year = year.split('/')
    collection = file_collection("#{path}/#{folder_name[2]}_#{year[0]}_#{Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[year[1].to_i]}.txt")
    collection.shift
    collection.each do |w|
      puts ( '+' * w[1].to_i).red + "#{w[1]}C", ('+' * w[3].to_i).blue + "#{w[3]}C"

    end
  end
end
```

What I have tried:
I have tried removing the w[1].to_i and tried printing it with static number.
I need this library as I have to print colored output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AbcSize is a metric which tells how many assignments, branches and conditions there are (more info [here](https://wiki.c2.com/?AbcMetric) or [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/code-metrics-and-you/)).

You can try to simplify your code, e. g. using extract method refactoring technique.

```
def print_element(element)
  puts ( '+' * element[1].to_i).red + "#{element[1]}C", ('+' * element[3].to_i).blue + "#{element[3]}C"
end
```

and then

```
  collection.each do |w|
    print_element(w)
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and it fixed my error for this function. I will try it on my other methods too with the same error.